# Topologically massive electromagnetism

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, maxwell-equations, chern-simons-theory

I am working with the Lagrangian given by

$$S = \int d^3 x (-\dfrac{-1}{4} F_{\mu} F^{\nu} + g \epsilon^{\mu \nu \lambda} A_{\mu} \partial_{\nu} A_{\lambda})$$

where $\epsilon^{012} = 1$.

I want to find the spectrum of the physical excitations of the field, specifically the mode expansion of the field and the dependency of $\omega$ on wave vector $\vec{k}$.

The field equations which I get are given by

$$\partial_{\nu} F^{\mu \nu} = 2 g \epsilon^{\alpha \nu \mu} (\partial_{\nu} A_{\alpha})$$. Now I choose the gauge $A_t = 0$, and fix the residual gauge by $\partial_i A^i = 0$. So the equations of motion become

$$\partial_2 A_1 = \partial_1 A_2,$$
$$\partial^2 A^1 = -2 g \partial_0 A_2$$
$$\partial^2 A^2 = + 2 g \partial_0 A_2$$

Now in the momentum space, if I use these 3 equations I get
$$(-\omega^2 + \vec{k_1}^2 + \vec{k_2}^2 - 2 i g  \omega k_2/ k_1) A_1 = 0$$

and
$$(-\omega^2 + \vec{k_1}^2 + \vec{k_2}^2 + 2 i g  \omega k_1/ k_2) A_2 = 0$$

My problem is, I am not getting a massive particle, and the dispersion relations for $A_1$ and $A_2$ are different. How do I solve my error? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you start with the above equations which you wrote, you have

$$(-\omega^2 + \vec{k_1}^2 + \vec{k_2}^2 - 2 i g  \omega k_2/ k_1) A_1 = 0$$

and
$$(-\omega^2 + \vec{k_1}^2 + \vec{k_2}^2 + 2 i g  \omega k_1/ k_2) A_2 = 0$$

Now comparing both of them we get

$$k_1^2 + k_2^2 = 0$$
and
$$-\omega^2 = 2 i \omega k_2 g/ k_1$$ 
and
$$-\omega^2 = -2 i \omega k_1 g/ k_2$$

which implies $\dfrac{i\omega k_1}{2g}=k_2$ and $\dfrac{-i\omega k_2}{2g}=k_1$

Now we can insert the above substitutions into $k_1^2 + k_2^2 = 0$ to get

$$\omega^2 = (2g)^2.$$

Hence you get a massive photon.

EDIT: The condition $k_1^2 + k_2^2 = 0$ might seem uncomfortable, it is obtained due to your choice of gauge.